# highlight the last clicked button in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am adding custom div elements to my google map  using code from here
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomExample
I have 3-4 buttons, how do I highlight the last clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a classname to the control border of all custom buttons before appending. E.g.:

```
controlUI.className = 'button';
```

Add a function to highlight the current custom button:

```
function hightlightButton(oElement) {
    var aButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; i++) {
        aButtons[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    oElement.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

In the click handlers add following lines to call the new function:

```
hightlightButton(this);
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/ZLYLP/).

Comment: so the button gets highlighted. but there is a slight problem, i have 3 buttons, all are grey, then on clicking it becomes yellow but on clicking the second button the first one still remains yellow

Comment: My mistake, in the explanation I've accidentally written `addClass` instead of `className`. I hope that you've already seen.